# Events being seen as duplicates by Gmail

Tags: google-calendar-api, gmail-api

Good afternoon guys. I'm having an issue when sending calendar invitations with PHP mailer. In order for the apple mail to accept the .ics files they need to be added as simple attachments to the invite email. The thing is when these are received by gmail accounts, with the attachment, plus a text/calendar part of the multipart email, they are being interpreted as duplicates.

I found the same issue here where including an organizer in the .ics file solved the issue, but that is not working for me. The topic is this one.

[Event invite results in Gmail displaying two events to add to gcal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29134400/event-invite-results-in-gmail-displaying-two-events-to-add-to-gcal)

Here's an example of an event

```
Content-Type: text/calendar; charset="UTF-8"; method=REQUEST
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

BEGIN:VCALENDAR

VERSION:2.0

PRODID:-//TQR//TQR//EN

CALSCALE:GREGORIAN

METHOD:REQUEST

BEGIN:VEVENT

DTSTART:20150610T140000Z

DTEND:20150610T180000Z

DTSTAMP:20150529T191215Z

ORGANIZER;CN=Attendee Status:mailto:TQR@xxx.com

UID:EVIDX497946349@xxx.com

ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-

ACTION;RSVP=TRUE;CN=testemail@xxx.com;X-NUM-GUESTS=0:mailto:testemail@xxx.com

CREATED:20150529T191215Z

DESCRIPTION:Test event

LAST-MODIFIED:20150529T191215Z

LOCATION:metting Office

SEQUENCE:1

STATUS:CONFIRMED

SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en-us:testevent

TRANSP:OPAQUE

END:VEVENT

END:VCALENDAR


--b2_f3ab419ed0e3cc3bbdb2525eab86f464
Content-Type: multipart/related;
    boundary="b3_f3ab419ed0e3cc3bbdb2525eab86f464"

--b3_f3ab419ed0e3cc3bbdb2525eab86f464
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
```

Any idea on what may be causing this?

Thank you !

Comment: Can you show us the code and where it's not working?

Comment: I added to the description an example of an event sent that is being seen as duplicate, and Thanks for helping!

Comment: Any Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe if the email address ends in '@gmail.com', you could only send the attachment OR the multipart calendar.

Comment: So there is nothing that I can change besides that right? In order to serve Apple mail and gmail I'll have to send invitations separately right ? For apple mail with the attachment and for gmail without the attachment. Or else Gmail will always see them as duplicates.